# running minimal app with xhp-lib v4 and hhvm v 4.81.1 throws error

Tags: php, hhvm, hacklang

I'm trying the following setup and am getting this error:

```
\nFatal error: Uncaught Error: Found top-level code in /home/user/code/xhp-simple/src/example.php:7\nStack trace:\n#0 (): main()\n#1 {main}
```

### Setup:

composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
        "hhvm/hhvm-autoload": "^3.1",
        "facebook/xhp-lib": "^4.0"
    }
}
```

src/index.hack

```
use type Facebook\XHP\HTML\div;
//  require_once(__DIR__."/../vendor/hh_autoload.hh");  // also tried here instead of in main

<<__EntryPoint>>
function main(): void {
  require_once(__DIR__."/../vendor/hh_autoload.hh");
  echo <div>{1 + 2}</div>;
}
```

hh_autoload.json

```
{"roots": ["src/"]}
```

run command:

```
hhvm -m server -p 8080 -d hhvm.server.default_document=./src/example.hack
```

I have hhvm v 4.83.1 installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you're running into the fact that hhvm-autoload hasn't caught up with the recent restrictions to top-level code. In particular, where `require_once` seems to no longer be allowed at the top level. With your `hh_autoload.json`, hhvm-autoload generates this `hh_autoload.hh`:

```
<?hh // partial
require_once(__DIR__.'/autoload.hack');
Facebook\AutoloadMap\initialize();
```

Where I believe that `require_once` is illegal. If you place this code in your main, it should work. I tested this with no problems on HHVM 4.84.0:

```
// src/index.hack
use type Facebook\XHP\HTML\div;

<<__EntryPoint>>
async function main(): Awaitable<void> {
    require_once(__DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.hack');
    Facebook\AutoloadMap\initialize();
    echo await (<div>{1 + 2}</div>)->toStringAsync();
}
```

```sh
$ # run with:
$ hhvm src/index.hack
```

Also note that [all rendering is async now with XHP-lib](https://hhvm.com/blog/2020/09/02/XHP-namespaces-and-syntax.html), so you can't just `echo` XHP objects directly; instead:

> Calls to `$xhp->toString()` need to be updated to `$xhp->toStringAsync()`.

---

I've just noticed [the updated README on hhvm-autoload](https://github.com/hhvm/hhvm-autoload#usage), where indeed `hh_autoload.hh` has been phased out and you need to need to generate the autoload map yourself (emphasis mine):

> Replace any references to `vendor/autoload.php` with `vendor/autoload.hack` **and call `Facebook\AutoloadMap\initialize()`**